# AngularJS - Best approach for taking data from factory and if not there use http service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my angularJS application, I have set data received from one controller's ajax and put in factory method to reuse in other controllers. The problem is when user reload page, this factory method is useless.

```
app.factory('factory', function () { 
    return {
        set: set,
        get: get
    }
});
app.controller ('testController', function ($scope, factory) { 
   if (factory.get('name')) {
        $scope.name= factory.get('name');
    } else {
     $http.get(url).then(function(res) {
        $scope.name= res.name;
        factory.set('name', res.name);
        });
    }
});
```

What is the best way to retrieve this check in factory method which will get value from factory, if not there take from http service and in controller common code needs handle these two cases that done factory method?

Here when data taken from http service it returns promise otherwise plain value.

Comment: @Aravind I would really appreciate your effort to answer this post. I'm afraid, you understood my question wrong way. I don't need to call service method each time to server for fetching data, if the data is stored in angular factory object/angular value. It should return that value instead of calling service method. Once you fetched data from service in any controller, there should not be call again to same service from any other controller. I like *Low Flying Pelican* answer, because it's only post that answer my post until now. I made some more change in his answer to make it what I wanted.

Comment: @Aravind It's already marked as accepted answer.

Comment: @Aravind Please don't remove comments, if comments are replied back. After you removed your couple of comments, it makes my previous comments nonsensical.

Comment: I m sorry, intention of removing them are not to waste memory of SO :P . Please do remove our general conversation comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will fetch data from server if the 'cachedResult' variable is not set, otherwise return a promise from the stored variable.

```
app.factory('factoryName', ['$http','$q', function($http,$q) {
        var cahedResult = null;

        var myMethod = function(args) {
            var deferred = $q.defer(); 

            if (cahedResult){
                deferred.resolve({ data : cahedResult });
                return deferred.promise;
            }

            $http.get(....).then(function(response){
                cahedResult =  response.data;
                deferred.resolve({ data : cahedResult });        
            },function(error){
                deferred.reject('error');  
            });
         }
       };

        return {
            myMethod : myMethod
        }
    ])
```

But you could also store the data in local storage or in a cookie when the first controller fetch the info so that it's available even if user refresh the browser.

Answer (score 0):

First create a factory :

```
app.factory('factoryName', ['$http','$q', function($http,$q) {
    return {
        getData : function(arg1,arg2) {
            return $http.get('/api-url'+arg1+'/'+arg2)
              .then(function(response) {
                if (typeof response.data === 'object') {
                    return response.data;
                } else {
                    return $q.reject(response.data);
                }

            }, function(response) {
                return $q.reject(response.data);
            });
         }
       }
     }])
```

Provide every api details in this factory, so you can use this factory in multiple controllers.

In Controller inject the factory (factoryName) as a dependency.

```
app.controller ('testController',['$scope', 'factoryName', function($scope, factoryName) {       
     factoryName.getData(arg1,arg2,...)
      .then(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      }, function(error){
        console.log(error);
      });
 }]);
```

For detailed description :- http://sauceio.com/index.php/2014/07/angularjs-data-models-http-vs-resource-vs-restangular/

Answer (score 0):

Directly return a promise from your factory

```
app.factory('factoryName', function () {
    var connectionurl ='...';   //Sample: http://localhost:59526/Services.svc
    return {
        connectionurl : connectionurl ,

        methodName: function (parameters) {
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: connectionurl + 'servicemethod_name'
            })}
}

    }
});
```

In this case your controller will look like

```
app.controller ('testController', function ($scope, factoryName) { 
   factoryName.methodName(parameters).then(function(){
   $scope.variable=response.data;
   /*binding your result to scope object*/
   }, function() {
   /*what happens when error occurs**/
   });
});
```

Other way is directly bind to a scope object through success callback function

```
app.factory('factoryName', function () {
    var connectionurl ='...';   //Sample: http://localhost:59526/Services.svc
    return {
        connectionurl : connectionurl ,
        methodName: function (parameters,successcallback) {
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: connectionurl + 'servicemethod_name'
            }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                successcallback(data);
            })
           .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
               $log.warn(data, status, headers, config);
           });
        }
    }
});
```

In this case your controller will look like

```
app.controller ('testController', function ($scope, factoryName) { 

   factoryName.methodName(parameters,function(response){
   /* your success actions*/
   $scope.variable=response;
   });
});
```

In the second case your error is handled in the factory itself. How ever you can also use errorcallback function.